# Android activity inside dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I want to start an activity inside a pop-up screen. Are there any suggestions for a quick change?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResults.this)
        .setTitle("Refine") 
        .setItems(/*catNames*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /* User clicked so do some stuff */
                String catName = catNames[which];
                String categoryIds = subCats.get(catName);
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //do nothing just dispose
            }
        })
        .create().show();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also apply this theme so your activity appears like a dialog box:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this thing dynamically?

Comment: This seems to theme it as a dialog but does not cause it to display as a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to start activity when user choose an item from your dialog, you can do it like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResults.this)
                    .setTitle("Refine") 
                    .setItems(/*catNames*/, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    /* User clicked so do some stuff */
                                    String catName = catNames[which];
                                    String categoryIds = subCats.get(catName);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchResults.this,YourActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    //do nothing just dispose
                            }
                    })
                    .create().show();
```

In your onClick() method you create an intent and pass it to startActivity() method.

Comment: I want to use intent as a view of the dialog.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm little bit confused here. Intent is an operation to be performed - it's not a View/ViewGroup component so it can't be used as a layout of a dialog. One of the operations that can be performed by intent is to start new activity - so maybe you want to set your custom layout for a dialog? Is that the case?